# What are the best libraries that can be used with React Native for best UI design

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo, mobile-application, ui-design

I'm currently developing the cross platform transportation app in React Native and Expo. Could anyone suggest the libraries that can be used to achieve the Best UI design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best UI you can use these libraries, I have used and T can recommend you these are the best libraries

1. react-native-paper
   https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/index.html
2. react-native-elements
   https://reactnativeelements.com/docs
3. gluestack-ui
   https://ui.gluestack.io/
   (previously native-base, https://docs.nativebase.io/installation)